# Django: 'Q' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-q

I have following APIView:

```
class SubmitFormAPIView(APIView):
    def put(self, request, pk):
        # some other codes
        
        form = Form.objects.get(id=pk)
        tu_filter, target_user = self._validate_target_user(request, form)
        user_status, created = UserFormStatus.objects.get_or_create(
            tu_filter,
            form_id=pk,
            user_id=request.user.pk
        )

        # Some other codes.
    
    def _validate_target_user(request, form):
        if some_conditions:
            return Q(), None
        else:
            try:
                target_user_id = int(request.GET.get('target_user_id))
            except ValueError:
                raise ValidationError()

            target_user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=target_user_id)
            return Q(target_user_id=target_user_id), target_user
```

but when django wants to execude `get_or_create` method, raises following error:

```
TypeError: 'Q' object is not iterable
```

Note: If `_validate_target_user()` returns `Q(), None`, no errors raised and view works fine. The error will be raised when `return Q(target_user_id=target_user_id), target_user` is returned.
 
I know, question information is not completed, just I want to know, what may cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a `Q` object, you can also just pass a dictionary of filters instead, like

```
{ 'target_user_id': target_user_id }
```

The you can run the `get_or_create` with `**tu_filter` as arguments, bypassing the need for `Q`.

```
class SubmitFormAPIView(APIView):
    def put(self, request, pk):
        # some other codes
        
        form = Form.objects.get(id=pk)
        tu_filter, target_user = self._validate_target_user(request, form)
        user_status, created = UserFormStatus.objects.get_or_create(
            **tu_filter,
            form_id=pk,
            user_id=request.user.pk
        )

        # Some other codes.
    
    def _validate_target_user(request, form):
        if some_conditions:
            return {}, None
        else:
            try:
                target_user_id = int(request.GET.get('target_user_id))
            except ValueError:
                raise ValidationError()

            target_user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=target_user_id)
            return { 'target_user_id': target_user_id }, target_user
```

Edit: As to what causes the error, my guess would be that using `Q` as part of your get_or_create statement is unclear to Django, because it doesn't know what to do with it in case the object needs to be created. A better approach would therefor be:

```
UserFormStats.objects.filter(tu_filter).get_or_create(form_id=pk, user_id=request.user.pk)
```

Comment: Yeah, your guess is right. `get_or_create()` cannot accept `Q()`.

Answer (score 2):

From the source of [**`get_or_create(...)`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/30e123ed351317b7527f632b3b7dc4e81e850449/django/db/models/query.py#L571-L594),

```
def get_or_create(self, defaults=None, **kwargs):
```

which indicating that the `get_or_create(...)` doesn't not accept any ***args*** unlike the `get()` or `filter(...)` methods.
Since your are executing the function as below, Python thinks that the `tu_filter` is the value for ***`default`*** parameter, which is expected to be an iterable.

```
get_or_create(
            tu_filter,
            form_id=pk,
            user_id=request.user.pk
        )
```